# URL Rewrite multilingual site for default language in MVC 5

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a multilingual site in MVC 5. I've implemented SEO friendly URL using attribute routing.
Here are the sample URL:

```
http://mycompany.com/en
http://mycompany.com/en/about_us
http://mycompany.com/en/product/type/item

http://mycompany.com/fr
http://mycompany.com/fr/about_us
http://mycompany.com/fr/product/type/item
```

Now, I need to remove language code (en) for default language English.

How can I achieve that using IIS URL rewrite tool?
Any alternate solution would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule. When user enters the url, it will be redirected to URL without language and show in the browser.

```
<rule name="rule2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="en(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bruce, it worked, although Now I have to write those new routes, which is obvious.